# a mistake in tui-nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, tui

I do the installation in my nuxt project as described in the documentation, but in the end I get an error:

```
The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

And there is no reactivity in the application. Help me please.

tui-nuxt: https://github.com/tui-nuxt/editor#getting-started

Comment: did you try to wrap your editor in `<client-only></client-only>` tag?

Comment: Yes, this removed the error, but tui-nuxt did not work reactively. Can you test tui-nuxt with yourself? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I do not understand how to get the value from TuiEditor

Comment: i cannot test it now, how does your `data` looks like?

Comment: data: () => ({
    content: ""
  }),

Comment: try it with this `data(){ return { content: "" } }`

Comment: It's the same if I write text in TuiEditor, and do console.log(content), i see empty string.